# How remote debug C#/.Net app on Linux when the app is run under a different user?

Tags: c#, linux, visual-studio, .net-core, remote-debugging

I'm running a .Net Core microservice on Linux (Ubuntu) and am trying to remote debug with Visual Studio over SSH. But the service is run under the user `svcuser` and my user is `mainuser`. Main user is in the same group as the service user.

In visual studio, I can see the process that the service is running under, but when I try to attach I get:

> One or more errors occurred. Failed to attach to process. The .Net Debugger has insufficient privileges to debug the process. To debug this process, vsdbg must be running with root permissions.

I checked in MS documentation but for Linux all they have is this: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/debugger/remote-debugging-dotnet-core-linux-with-ssh?view=vs-2019 which has no info on running the service with a different user

And the only info they have on fixing such a problem is for windows only: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/debugger/error-the-microsoft-visual-studio-remote-debugging-monitor-on-the-remote-computer-is-running-as-a-different-user?view=vs-2019

Comment: "To debug this process, vsdbg must be running with root permissions."

Comment: @LexLi There has to be a way without root permissions

Comment: Have you found solution for this.

Comment: @NikolaGaić No, we ended up just restricting this to environments where we could set the user to be the same

Answer (score 10):

If you have `sudo` privileges then this is relatively easy, and can be kept secured to those users with `sudo` privs. Avoids needing to reconfigure users/environments, and allows you to debug any process on the machine regardless of which user account it is running as.

If you use Visual Studio to make an initial attempt to debug you will find that a `~/.vs-debugger` folder has been created in the home directory of the user account you were attempting to use. This command will help you locate the `vsdbg` binary which was installed. You can install VsDbg manually but I find leveraging the automated process is easier. If you are using VSCode this becomes a manual process, and an exercize left for the reader, but I would still use VS2019 IDE to prep the target just to keep things consistent between tools.

```sh
find ~ | grep vsdbg
```

For my installation the binary is located at `~/.vs-debugger/vs2019/vsdbg` and this path will most likely change over time.

First, rename the binary to something convenient:

```sh
mv ~/.vs-debugger/vs2019/vsdbg ~/.vs-debugger/vs2019/vsdbg-bin
```

Second, create a script to replace the binary:

```sh
touch ~/.vs-debugger/vs2019/vsdbg
chmod 770 ~/.vs-debugger/vs2019/vsdbg
nano ~/.vs-debugger/vs2019/vsdbg
```

The script content might look something like this, note the full path to `vsdbg-bin`, the use of `$@` ensures all command-line args passed to your script are forwarded to VsDbg.

```sh
#!/bin/bash
sudo ~/.vs-debugger/vs2019/vsdbg-bin $@
```

Now retry your debug session from Visual Studio, if you did things correctly you should be able to attach to any remote process on the target machine using SSH->VsDbg. "Works on my machine." ;) This was confirmed with `VS2019 16.8.4`, `.NET 5.0`, and `VsDbg 16.9.20122.2` debugging an ASP.NET Core application running on `Debian 5.4.8 (x64)` launched by systemd under a service user account in Azure. "Sweet."

HTH!

Comment: Excellent answer!

Comment: sweet indeed, thank you

Comment: This is so elegant. Thanks! I am no longer getting that error!. However my debugger is still not attaching, but it is probably something else, I am not able to hit the breakpoints.

Comment: Hi, Thanks for your solution. This looks like it should work.. but I'm not getting prompted to supply the sudo password? How do I get the $@ to be replaced with the sudo password? Thanks.
I'm using RHEL and when I just do "sudo ~/.vs-debugger/vs2019/vsdbg-bin <thesudopassword>" on the commandline it still prompts me for the password.. so its ignoring the passwd on the commandline...

Comment: @Vida you probably want to modify the sudoers file on the target host so a password is not required by sudo, otherwise this will not work. by default most linux distributions configure sudo to prompt for a password. i really have to discourage against hardcoding/passing a password in the clear, even if you control the target host it creates an attack vector that wouldn't otherwise exist, a `NOPASSWD` sudoer would be more secure. that said, you may be able to leverage the info in this Q&A: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/391796/pipe-password-to-sudo-and-other-data-to-sudoed-command

Comment: for anyone not familiar with configuring a `NOPASSWD` sudoer, have a look at this Q&A: https://askubuntu.com/questions/334318/sudoers-file-enable-nopasswd-for-user-all-commands

Comment: @luisgepeto Did you ever figure out your issue?