# How to run and debug a Linux executable in Visual Studio 2019 as root?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2019

I am using Visual Studio 2019 to develop a Linux executable, and the remote machine is an Ubuntu 16 VM. Right now everything works fine and debugging works like a charm, but the problem is that I need to run that program as root because its doing stuff like insmod, and right now when I start debugging with F5, it starts as the normal user.

I couldn't find any option in the Visual studio's project properties for specifying that the program needs to run as root when I press F5. Is there anyway that I can achieve this? Meaning when I start debugging it, it needs to run as root.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61281565/how-remote-debug-c-net-app-on-linux-when-the-app-is-run-under-a-different-user

Comment: @HansPassant There is no ~/.vs-debugger folder in the home directory of the target Ubuntu machine, there is only a .vs folder which is empty. And find ~ | grep vsdbg returns empty as well

Comment: @HansPassant Nevermind, I solved it by changing the /etc/sudoers (as the target is a test machine and security is not an issue) and adding "ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD:ALL" to my username. I guess a cleaner way is to add only the commands that I need, but who cares its a test machine.